# approval workflow is not working?

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow, approval-process, content-approval

I made it with a participant list. It is sending mail to this list members. I am clicking Approve, and then the outcome is being "Approved" for me but the other members' outcomes are still blank and the task is not finishing. How to do this?

[image]

Comment: What kind of workflow are you using?  Something you made in SP Designer or is this an OOTB workflow or is it a content approval workflow e.g. triggered by checking in a document?

Comment: I used Globally Reusable Workflow , Publishing Approval. It was ready, only i changed it for my site. If an editor click "Publish a Major Version" , my workflow is triggered. I am using Sharepoint Designer 2010

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you still need two more approvals for the document?  Document approval could be set to `All at once (in parallel)` so there are three approval tasks.  One is completed, two remain.

You could try changing this to 'Serial' instead if you would rather tasks are only set one at a time, in a chain.  It is also worth checking to see if `Expand Groups` is ticked - if it is, then an approval task will be set to each member of an approval group.  As you see in the picture below, I have two approval groups instead of people; when active, the `Expand Groups` setting assigns a task to each group member.  If it is not active then a single person from a group can approve the document on behalf of the group.

On your document library -> Workflow Settings -> Select your approval workflow ->

[image: workflow completion conditions]

Comment: I choose Parallel approval. Expand Group is checked. but ıt is waiting for everybody to approve . How can slove this?

Comment: Parallel approval isn't causing the issue.  Regarding 'Expand Group' - if the box is ticked, Sharepoint will have created an approval task for each member of the group.  If this isn't how you want to configure it, untick the 'Expand Group' box.  Then there will only be one task created per group.  i.e. if you have two Approval Groups with 3 members in each group, that makes 6 approval tasks.  If you untick the 'Expand Group' box there will only be 2 approval tasks.